# create EAR using netbeans 7.2

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, war

I created **web project** and **ejb** in seperately using **netbeans 7.2** . Is there any possibility to create new **Enterprise Application project** and add both **web and ejb projects** to it ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Just Import the WAR file in to the Netbeans using the options as NewProject --> Enterprise and Packaged Archive
2. Create an EnterpriseApplication and delete the default ejb and war components created by Netbeans
3. Click - EnterpriseApplication - new JavaEE module and add the War file that had already been 
   exported as a packaged ARchive

Now build the project you can find the EAR file in the dist folder.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, after creating EAR project, go to the Project's panel in the left side of NetBeans, then, right-click on the new EAR project just created, then, click "Add Java EE Module...". You must see in a small window : the EJB and Web projects that u've created before listed in, u selected them to add to the EAR project.